# C# updating from double to timespan, how to use Projeckts.Sum?

Tags: c#

Basically what I am doing is, if I report hour on more than 2 projects. I take the hours from both projects sum that up into one and compare them to the time I said I work. 
So if I say I work 8 hours total. and I write 3 hours on project1 and 5 hours on project2 I just take the sum of both projects and compare it with my `WorkedHours` if it match up I continue, this is how I do it.

```
if (emptyHours > 1 || (emptyHours == 0 && projectData.Projects.Sum(x => x.Hours) != projectData.Times.WorkedHours))
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("hours_" + project.First(), "Antalet timmar stämmer ej överens.");
}
```

However, having some rounding issues on small numbers so I though I would use `Timespan` instead. But sadly I just can't do this. when trying this:

```
if (emptyHours > 1 || (emptyHours == 0 && projectData.Projects.Sum(x => x.TempHours) != projectData.Times.WorkedHours))
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("hours_" + project.First(), "Antalet timmar stämmer ej överens.");
}
```

I could just do this:

```
testhours = (TimeSpan) ( testhours + projectData.Projects[projectData.Projects.Count - 1].TempHours);
```

Not sure if that would be a good solution though. But it seems to work so far.